# Regression model with changing coefficients

Tags: regression, interaction

I want to find a coefficient between two variables, while the coefficient could vary based on the level of a third variable.

For example, a car could run 20 miles by buring 1 gallon of gas, if the temperature is above 40, otherwise, it will be 15 miles per gallon. The coefficient, 20 or 15, will be estimated by the data points (miles run, gallons burned, temperature). How should I build the model?

Answer (score 1):

You are describing an *interaction*.  To include an interaction in your model, form a product term by multiplying the two variables in question.  For example, the interaction term for your situation would be: ${\rm gallons}\times {\rm temperature>40}$.